# C# Tests failing using XUnit and EF InMemoryDatabase

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, xunit

I'm adding integration tests to a project using XUnit and EF core InMemoryDatabase.

Currently, there are 2 Test classes: RolesControllerTest and UsersControllerTest.

For some reason, when I run tests one by one, they pass, but if I run them all at once, some of them fail.

If I mark the two classes with

```
[Collection("Our Test Collection #1")]
```

According to XUnit documentation: "If we need to indicate that multiple test classes should not be run in parallel against one another, then we place them into the same test collection. This is simply a matter of decorating each test class with an attribute that places them into the same uniquely named test collection". https://xunit.net/docs/running-tests-in-parallel

All the tests pass in both Test Classes if they are part of the same Collection (not running in parallel).

1. This is the Fixture that uses the WebApplicationFactory:

   ```
   public class TestFactory<TProgram, TDbContext> : WebApplicationFactory<TProgram>
        where TProgram : class where TDbContext : DbContext
        {
            protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
            {
                builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
                {
                    services.RemoveDbContext<TDbContext>();
                    services.AddDbContext<TDbContext>(options =>
                    {
                        options.UseInMemoryDatabase("TestDB");
                    });

                    services.EnsureDbCreated<TDbContext>();
                });
            }
        }
   ```
2. This is the TestFactoryBase class (Uses the previous TestFactory Fixture):

   ```
    public class TestFactoryBase : IClassFixture<TestFactory<Program, ADBContext>>, IDisposable
    {
        public HttpClient _client;
        public ADBContext _dbContext;

        public TestFactoryBase(TestFactory<Program, ADBContext> factory) {
            _client = factory.CreateClient();

            var scope = factory.Services.CreateScope();
            var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
            _dbContext = scopedServices.GetService<ADBContext>();
            _dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        { 
            _client.Dispose();
            _dbContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();
        }
    }
   ```
3. This is the Role test class:

   ```
    public class RolesControllerTest : TestFactoryBase, IClassFixture<RolesRepositoryFixture>
    {
        private IRoleRepository _rolesRepository;

        public RolesControllerTest(TestFactory<Program, ADBContext> factory, RolesRepositoryFixture rolesRepository) : base(factory)
        {
            _rolesRepository = rolesRepository.CreateRoleRepository(_dbContext);
        }
    // Tests...
   ```
4. This is a test:

   ```
      [Fact(DisplayName = "GetByIdAsync returns a role model by Id")]
      public async Task GetByIdAsync_ReturnsRoleModel()
      {
         var roleInDb = await _rolesRepository.CreateAsync(new RoleModel
         {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Name = "Role A",
            Description = "Role A Description",
            CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
            UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now,
            Deleted = false,
          });

          var response = await _client.GetFromJsonAsync<RoleModel>($"/api/roles/{roleInDb.Id}");

          response.ShouldNotBeNull();
          response.ShouldBeOfType<RoleModel>();
          response.Id.ShouldBe(roleInDb.Id);
          response.Name.ShouldBe(roleInDb.Name);
          response.Description.ShouldBe(roleInDb.Description);
      }
   ```

I've been trying to debug the tests, but haven't found the exact problem yet.

**How can I fix it without having to mark all Test Classes as part of the same collection?**

Comment: what is the error message you get? Perhaps the problem is that you share the same database for multiple concurrent tests. To resolve this you could create a database per class to resolve concurrency problems.

Comment: When I run all the tests in Parallel (at the same time) they fail with http status 505 or 404. I think you're right. The database name is the same for all the tests, if a test is interacting with the database and it is disposed, it would explain why they fail.

Comment: For tests to reflect real-life you should have a context per test, otherwise tests will always affect one another. The database can be shared among tests if each test rolls back its artifacts. Also, don't use InMemory: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/testing-without-the-database#in-memory-provider